# Convert timedelta of days into years

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, google-colaboratory, timedelta

I have a `timedelta64[ns]` column (final_df['Age']) in a dataframe, created by subtracting a `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` column (final_df["Contact Birth Date"]) from a `datetime64[ns]` variable (today_date). However, when I print the dataframe, it shows the timedelta in the number of days, like so:

5511 days

I want it to print just the number of years. I have not had any luck converting it to an int or a datetime object. Is there a way to convert the '5511 days' to '15 years' or just '15'? If it helps, I am using google colab.

Here is my code for today_date and final_df['Age']. I imported datetime as dt.

```
today_date = pd.to_datetime(dt.date.today())
final_df['Age'] = today_date - final_df["Contact Birth Date"]
```

Comment: why not floor-divide by the average number of days in a year; `5511 // 365.2425` ? Or `(today_date - final_df["Contact Birth Date"]).dt.days // 365.2425` in your code sample.

Comment: ok the second one worked, thank you so much! I should have thought about wrapping the entire expression in parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you, check this out- > `timedelta(days=5511).days`  this returns days in `int` and then you can divide it to 365 and you will take years.   `timedelta(days=5511).days/365` .